# Protobuf version mismatch on Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I have a TensforFlow-based Python application that runs fine on my PC with Windows 10. However when I transfer my app to another PC with Ubuntu 20.04.4 using the same environment I get the following error:

```
[libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:83] This program was compiled against version 3.9.2 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, which is not compatible with the installed version (3.19.4).  Contact the program author for an update.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.pb.cc".)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have no idea where the older version of protobuf (3.9.2) comes from.

```
pip show protobuf

Name: protobuf
Version: 3.19.4
Summary: Protocol Buffers
Home-page: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/
Author:
Author-email:
License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: /home/username/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: tensorboard, tensorflow
```

I don't have any other versions of protocol buffers installed:

```
protoc --version

Command 'protoc' not found, but can be installed with:

snap install protobuf           # version 3.14.0, or
apt  install protobuf-compiler  # version 3.6.1.3-2ubuntu5

See 'snap info protobuf' for additional versions.
```

On both machines TensorFlow was installed via pip without any local building / compiling.

```
pip install tensorflow==2.3.0
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out that the problem was caused by the order of imports in my Python files. I had to put all TensorFlow-related imports in first place:

```
# Original order of imports that caused the error on Ubuntu

import detectron2
import EasyOCR
import Tensorflow


# Modified order of imports that works fine on Ubuntu

import Tensorflow # in first place!  
import detectron2
import EasyOCR
```

I also had to rearrange **all** upper level imports in order to put my module with Tensorflow import in first place:

```
# Original order of imports that caused the error on Ubuntu

import local module without Tensorflow imports 1
import local module without Tensorflow imports 2
import local module without Tensorflow imports 3
import local module with Tensorflow imports inside


# Modified order of imports that works fine on Ubuntu

import local module with Tensorflow imports inside # in first place!    
import local module without Tensorflow imports 1
import local module without Tensorflow imports 2
import local module without Tensorflow imports 3
```